# Comparison of 2 queries (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries. Are they identical?

```
DELETE FROM t1 
USING t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 using(key) 
WHERE t2.key is null

DELETE t1 
FROM t1  
LEFT JOIN t2 using(key) 
WHERE t2.key is null
```

If yes , which one is more efficient?

Comment: The first one doesn't look valid. You can't have `USING` without a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

In my view both are identical as I know from this syntax:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Multiple-table syntax:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

Or:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

As concern about which of them are more efficient? It depends upon situation mean where and when we are using this.

Read this for better experience: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html